# I am unable to login into my wp-admin

Tags: wp-admin, privacy

before happening this error i go to the general setting and on the place of HTTP i did HTTPS by mistake. but now i am unable to login into my `wp-admin` panel

Whenever i type `www.mydomain.com/wp-admin/` the privacy  error comes:

> Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from
>   www.mydomain.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).
>   Learn more NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
>
> Automatically send some system information and page content to
>   Google to help detect dangerous apps and sites. Privacy policy

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by changes `site_url` and `home_url` in your database.

If you have access to your database(phpmyadmin) go to `options` table and change `site_url` and `home_url` from HTTPS to HTTP.

You can also change it through `wp-config` file.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.example.com');
```

See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL for possible methods.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to fix this problem real quick is via the database, within 10 seconds it be fixed.

Open phpmyadmin via your cPanel and then run the following queries to update the site urls and home url:

```
UPDATE wp_options
SET option_value="http://www.example.com/" where option_name ="siteurl"
```

and also run another query:

```
UPDATE wp_options
SET option_value="http://www.example.com/" where option_name ="home"
```

Note:

- Replace http://www.example.com/ with your domain URLS
- Above queries will 100% function if you have your databsae extension as wp_ set.

Answer (score 0):

Access your website using HTTP protocol. You will not face this error.
http://www.yourdomainname.com/wp-admin/

SSL is not installed on domain hence you are facing this issue.

If you have added HTTPS instead of HTTP for WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL  then please update it on web.config file. You will have to use HTTP.